# Create public REST API from firebase

Tags: javascript, rest, api, firebase

I am building a simple web app using Firebase as the backend.

As part of that app I would like to expose a public API so that authenticated users can push or pull data from the app.

However I do not wish to expose the generated URL that Firebase have provided me for development.

Do I have to route requests to my API domain to Firebase through my app, or is there some way of giving a firebase API a public domain?

Comment: You need to build the API on your backend.

Comment: From the sound of your question you are just hosting your site on Firebase?  You need to host an actual backend to do what you want. And if you start doing that, than you can just as well host your site on that backend, so I guess my suggestion boils down to this: Switch to a different hosting provider that doesn't just host client facing stuff, but actual backends for webapps.

Comment: My app is a simple SPA, so could be hosted with Firebase, or any other host. I was hoping to avoid having to run any serverside code at all, host the site on nothing but a scalable webserverand make all API queries, both external and in-app, through Firebase.

Comment: Well that's fine if you just have a client facing website, but if you want to do something server side - like provide an API - then you need a server to do that on. You can also continue to host your side on Firebase, you can just implement the API on something like [**Google App Engine**](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/) or if you can get into the alpha of [**Cloud Functions**](https://cloud.google.com/functions/) even better - it seems that [**Cloud Functions**](https://cloud.google.com/functions/) might be exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Xaver, very enlightening. Seems I am stuck with some kind of middleman code, but at least my dream of a serverless app can be real. If you want to write all that up as an answer I'd be happy to mark it solved.

Comment: [Cloud Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/) might be useful as well.

Comment: Hey, Look at this article - https://codeburst.io/building-a-serverless-api-using-firebase-cloud-functions-e5a6be42144c

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/) domain to [route/rewrite requests to your Cloud Functions backend](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions) without ever having to expose the project-specific https endpoint for that project.

Comment: How will this work with Single Page App? So for example: 'somewebsite.com/api' which would also be redirecting to a function but also has a root somewebsite.com using `**`